# How I can remove an Item for a select option html pressing a button with php

Tags: php, html, css

Im tryng to create a simple application that when you click on the send button it removes the
option that is selected. I only can use PHP and no JS.

```
    <form action="prueba.php" method="POST">
      <select name="cars" id="cars">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
        
      <input type="submit" value="Eliminar">
<form>
```

Comment: PHP is a server side scripting language, it works on the server only. You can't do anything with PHP on client's browser.

Comment: I know that but theres any solution to create that without using JS. Im using a server side,

Comment: At least I don't know if something like that exists :(

Comment: Technically it is possible. For anyone that wants to create it, here is the idea: Put the options into an array and display them. When the user submits via POST, get the value of their post and remove that option from the array and show that array on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some sort of data storage. In this case I'm using sessions, but you could use a database.

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['removed_options'] )){
    $_SESSION['removed_options'] = [];
}
if(isset($_POST['Eliminar'])){
    $_SESSION['removed_options'][] = $_POST['cars'];
}

$options = ["volvo", "saab", "opel", "audi"];
?>

<form action="prueba.php" method="POST">
    <select name="cars" id="cars">
        <?php foreach(array_diff($options, $_SESSION['removed_options']) as $option): ?>
            <option value="<?= $option ?>"><?= ucfirst($option) ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Eliminar" name="Eliminar">
<form>
```

You could also possibly store the options in a hidden field on the frontend now that I think about it.